# Database connection fails

Tags: c#, sql-server, installation, desktop-application

I have written c# application that uses mdf file for database.when i make setup of that project and runs on other computer having dotnetframework and sql server compact 3.5 then id dose not runs and exception is shown saying something sql server not found or not ready for connection something like that what should i do

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mdf is not for sql server compact edition, it is for the real sql server. You need to deploy it to Sql Server Express edition or higher.

**Edit:**
You can install [SQL server express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx) or if you want to use the sql compact server you need to create a "local database" in visual studio.

When adding a mdf-database to your visual studio project is is attached to your local sql express database server behind the scenes when you start your project.

Comment: ok what should i install at client machine where there is no visual studio installed and one more thing when i made this application i didnot used sql server seperately i only added mdf file and then got connection string from visual studio not by launching sql server express or anything sol please suggest me a solution

Comment: @Afnan, I updated my answer with a link, and a note about compact sql.

Comment: thanl you but when i install this then I have to start managment studio and then make tables again and all that and then feed my new connection string again or just install and that previously created mdf file attached will do that?? sorry if it is a dumb question

Comment: @Afnan, I'm not sure, but I think you only need to install the SQL express and the file should be autoattached thanks to the `AttachDbFilename` part of your connection string.